# Retrieving Long Data Type using Stored Procedures in Oracle

Tags: visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm having problems retrieving a data with LONG data type in my Oracle database. Before it was working fine when the particular column is in VARCHAR2 type, but since I needed more space to store larger data, I decided to use LONG type instead.

I'm retrieving the data using a stored procedure, the following code calls the stored procedure from C#:

```
internal static Issue GetIssueById(int issueId)
    {
        List<OracleParameter> p = new List<OracleParameter>();

        // params
        p.Add(new OracleParameter("p_IssueId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, issueId, ParameterDirection.Input));
        p.Add(new OracleParameter("p_Cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));

        // perform get
        using (DataTable dt = OracleDataAccessor.ExecuteDataTable(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString,
            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            "sp_Issues_GetByIssueId",
            p.ToArray()))
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                // could not get new id
                throw new Exception("Could not find issue with Id: " + issueId);
            }
            else
            {
                // get new Issue
                return new Issue(dt.Rows[0]);
            }
        }
```

And here's the stored procedure:

```
 create or replace 
Procedure sp_Issues_GetByIssueId
(
       p_IssueId IN Number,
       p_Cursor OUT Sys_RefCursor
)
IS

BEGIN

  OPEN p_Cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM Issues i
  WHERE i.IssueId = p_IssueId;

END sp_Issues_GetByIssueId;
```

I am trying to get a full row in the ISSUES table with 15 columns using the issueId as the primary key and I'm having problems retrieving the column with a LONG data type, to be specific, I cannot retrieve the data from it. Like I said, before when its type was VARCHAR2, there were no issues and the code works perfectly fine. Did I miss something here, or is there something wrong with the LONG data type? If so, what are the possible work-around? If possible, I still want to use the LONG data type instead of other types.

To add, I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

`LONG` has been deprecated since the 8.1.5 days and has a number of limitations.  `LONG` should be avoided at all costs.

If you want to store text data that is more than 4,000 bytes (32,000 bytes in 12c), you'll want to use a `CLOB`, not a `LONG`.